# execute some code at a certain time daily

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I execute some code, once a day.
e.g. call MyMethod() at 3pm every day.
(provided the app is running of course)...

Im trying to do this in c# winforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to run something at the same time every day, you can use the built in [task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler).

You can setup a daily schedule that will execute your application at the same time every day.

Otherwise, in your application you will need to setup a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) and check in the tick event if the current time is 3pm and only call your method at that point.

I would have suggested a windows service, but as you stated that you only need the method to run if the application is already running, this is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

The task scheduler is the best option. If you need to do it inside a .NET application there is no component that allows you to trigger an event at a specific time. But you can set up a Timer to raise an event every minute (for example, but you can set up a smaller o bigger interval depending on your needs), then in the handler you check the current time and if it is 3pm you can execute your code, else do nothing.

Comment: he ask for a running application so task scheduler is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Service and a Timer!

check out codeproject's simple windows server:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want more control you can create a Windows Service. Simply inherit from System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase and add a timer on the OnStart override. Install your windows service on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is quite old but I reached it for the need expressed in the subject. I ended up with a simpler code using just DateTime class. I tested it and it's working just fine, here's the code:

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, hour, min), 0);
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now > start)
        {
            start = start.AddDays(1);
            ....do_your_stuff.....
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
```

I hope it can be useful.